Invalid Pycharm Interpreter after changing directory for project
I changed the directory of a project in PyCharm then deleted and configured a new local python interpreter even after the new interpreter was configured PyCharm still gives me a Invalid Local Interpreter error.
(By directory change I mean I moved my project into a new folder made inside the same parent folder the project already was.)
I tried to delete the .venv folder (both from the PyCharm file list and from the Windows file explorer) I also deleted all other PyCharm created files and folders except the .py files I had written

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
